# How to get correct position after filtering the adapter?

Tags: android

Please help to solve the problem. My adapter works perfectly when I click it just as it is,  and shows the correct position. But when i search the value using filter and click the filtered adapter the result shows the value as in first position and i get the position=1, but actually i need the position=9 for example. how to get the correct position of array item after i filter the adapter?

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    public  RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private final static String TAG = "MyActivity";
    public View view;
    public String value;
    public EditText editText;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        View row_content = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.example_item, null);
        view  = (View) row_content.findViewById(R.id.view);
         editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        value = editText.getText().toString();



        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        }

        createExampleList();
        buildRecyclerView();




        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {



            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                filter(s.toString());

            }
        });


    }

    private void filter(String text) {
        ArrayList<ExampleItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ExampleItem item : mExampleList) {

            if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }

        mAdapter.filterList(filteredList);


    }

    private void createExampleList() {

        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.us, "English"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.chi, "简体中文"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.chi, "繁體中文"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.es, "Esperanto"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fr, "français"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.it, "Italiano"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.jp, "日本語"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.kr, "한국어"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ru, "русский"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.esp, "Español"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.pt, "Português"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.unar, "العربية"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.bd, "বাংলা"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.in, "हिन्दी"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.de, "Deutsch"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.za, "Afrikaans"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.al, "Shqip"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.et, "አማርኛ"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.am, "Հայերեն"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.az, "azərbaycan dili"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.es, "euskara"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.by, "беларуская мова"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ba, "bosanski jezik"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.bs, "български език"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ad, "català"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ca, "нохчийн мотт"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.cor, "corsu"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.hr, "hrvatski jezik"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.cz, "čeština"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.dk, "dansk"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.nl, "Nederlands"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ee, "eesti"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.fl, "suomi"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.nl, "Frysk"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ga, "Galego"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ge, "ქართული"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.in, "ગુજરાતી"));


    }

    private void buildRecyclerView() {

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {



                String string =  mExampleList.get(position).getText1();
                int img= mExampleList.get(position).getImageResource();
                Log.e(TAG,"LANGUAGE IS: " + string);



                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("NAME", string);
                intent.putExtra("POSITION",Integer.toString(position));
                intent.putExtra("PHOTO", img);
                startActivity(intent);





            }
        });

    }


}
```

public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;


public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}


public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    public ImageView mImageView;
    public TextView mTextView1;



    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                   if(listener != null){
                       int position = getAdapterPosition();
                       if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){


                           listener.onItemClick(position);

                       }
                   }

            }
        });


    }
}

public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
    mExampleList = exampleList;

}

@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item,
            parent, false);
    ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
    return evh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
}

public void filterList(ArrayList<ExampleItem> filteredList) {
    mExampleList = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: If you can provide your adapter class function. peoples will find out the issue easily.

Comment: please could you check again, i've added the adapter class

Answer (score 0):

The reason for incorrect index - You are using class variable (mExampleList) to get data on “mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener” but adapter returns filtered data.

You need to get filtered data from adapter.

You can add function to return adapter’s data inside your adapter. And you can use that on mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener

For e.g:

```
private static class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    /*   ADAPTER’S FUNCTIONS   */

    public ArrayList<ExampleItem> getDataList() {
        return mExampleList;
    }

}

private void buildRecyclerView() {

    /*   OTHER LOGICS HERE   */

    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {

            // BELOW IS - YOUR CODE

    /*String string = mExampleList.get(position).getText1();
    int img = mExampleList.get(position).getImageResource();*/

            // THIS IS NEW WORKING CODE

            String string = mAdapter.getDataList().get(position).getText1();
            int img = mAdapter.getDataList().get(position).getImageResource();

            Log.d(TAG, "LANGUAGE IS: " + string);

            Log.d("NAME", string);
            Log.d("POSITION", Integer.toString(position));
            Log.d("PHOTO", String.valueOf(img));
        }
    });

}
```

Please check my completed code below.

```
package com.example.myapplication.java;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.myapplication.R;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
    private final static String TAG = "MyActivity";
    public String value;
    public EditText editText;

    static class ExampleItem {

        private int image;
        private String text1;

        ExampleItem(int image, String text1) {
            this.image = image;
            this.text1 = text1;
        }

        int getImageResource() {
            return image;
        }

        String getText1() {
            return text1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        value = editText.getText().toString();

        createExampleList();
        buildRecyclerView();

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void filter(String text) {
        ArrayList<ExampleItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ExampleItem item : mExampleList) {

            if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }

        mAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }

    private void createExampleList() {

        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "English"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "简体中文"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "繁體中文"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Esperanto"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "français"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Italiano"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "日本語"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "한국어"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "русский"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Español"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Português"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "العربية"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "বাংলা"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "हिन्दी"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Deutsch"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Afrikaans"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Shqip"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "አማርኛ"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Հայերեն"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "azərbaycan dili"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "euskara"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "беларуская мова"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "bosanski jezik"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "български език"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "català"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "нохчийн мотт"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "corsu"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "hrvatski jezik"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "čeština"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "dansk"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Nederlands"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "eesti"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "suomi"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Frysk"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Galego"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "ქართული"));
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "ગુજરાતી"));
    }

    private void buildRecyclerView() {

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {

                // BELOW IS - YOUR CODE

                /*String string = mExampleList.get(position).getText1();
                int img = mExampleList.get(position).getImageResource();*/

                // THIS IS NEW WORKING CODE

                String string = mAdapter.getDataList().get(position).getText1();
                int img = mAdapter.getDataList().get(position).getImageResource();

                Log.d(TAG, "LANGUAGE IS: " + string);

                Log.d("NAME", string);
                Log.d("POSITION", Integer.toString(position));
                Log.d("PHOTO", String.valueOf(img));
            }
        });
    }

    private static class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
        private OnItemClickListener mListener;

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick(int position);
        }

        void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            ImageView mImageView;
            TextView mTextView1;

            ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
                super(itemView);

                mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                listener.onItemClick(position);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
            mExampleList = exampleList;
        }

        @NotNull
        @Override
        public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
            return new ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

            holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
            holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mExampleList.size();
        }

        void filterList(ArrayList<ExampleItem> filteredList) {
            mExampleList = filteredList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        ArrayList<ExampleItem> getDataList() {
            return mExampleList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding these lines in your `filter` method

```
mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(filteredList); //with filted list
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will initiate adapter with new filtered list and it will give you right position

This is not a optimal option but It works